# Invite a friend with token which will be asked during signup : Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an application where I want to allow users to invite their friend and their friends will be sent an email with token. So when the friend registers, there will be Enter token here textbox where the friend has to enter the token sent by email.

Registration will be allowed with token and without token also.

Can anyone please help, how can I achieve this?

I am using Devise, Rails 4, ruby 2.0!

Comment: https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable

Comment: I am trying to use devise_invitable but I can't get resource_name in my invitations_controller. Can you please help, how can I get that value? 

I get the following error :
<code>NoMethodError - undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass:
  devise (3.2.2) app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:22:in `resource_name'

</code>

I have followed the exact instructions on the link.

Answer (score 0):

At its simplest:

- On form submissions check for a value in the token input field
- If a token has been entered, validate this against your existing users
- If valid, register the user and execute your logic associated with a friend registering
- If not valid, return the user to the form with an error message

If you wanted a nicer user experience, you would validate the token prior to the form being submitted using ajax.

Comment: Thats exactly what I thought. I don't want to do all of that manually. So can you please suggest something else.